# C++ expecting parentheses when one isn't needed?

Tags: c++

I am having a problem that I can not figure out, I am still very new to c++.
Here is a code snippet:

```
#define secondsInHour 3600;          
#define secondsInMinute 60;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int totalSeconds;
    int convertedHours;
    int convertedMinutes;
    int convertedSeconds;

    cout << "Enter time in seconds: ";
    cin  >> totalSeconds;
    cout << endl;

    convertedHours = totalSeconds / secondsInHour;                          
    convertedMinutes = (totalSeconds - (convertedHours*secondsInHour))/secondsInMinute;             //D

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run, I receive the following error: expected a ')' 
Can anyone explain?  The error refers to the second to last line.

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2015.  Sorry I was referring the wrong line.  The line producing the error is the "convertedMinutes = ...."

Comment: Please make your example fully reproducible by showing the declarations and values for all types.

Comment: Can you provide a larger context of your code? As well as the full compiler error message?

Comment: The error doesn't make sense. There must be something else about your code you're not showing here. As a note, none of the four parentheses in your second line are needed. What happens if you take them all out?

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: You should not have `;` at the end of your `#define` statements. Those are substituted along with the numbers, leading to your syntax problems.

Comment: Learn how to look at the preprocessor output on your platform. That will make the problem obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the semicolons in your `#define` macros.

When the preprocessor substitutes the text of the macros into the code, the code that the compiler sees looks like this:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int totalSeconds;
int convertedHours;
int convertedMinutes;
int convertedSeconds;

cout << "Enter time in seconds: ";
cin  >> totalSeconds;
cout << endl;

convertedHours = totalSeconds / 3600;;                          
convertedMinutes = (totalSeconds - (convertedHours*3600;))/60;;             //D

return 0;
```

See how the extra semicolon from the `secondsInHour` macro breaks the `convertedMinutes` expression?

You need to remove the semicolons:

```
#define secondsInHour 3600    
#define secondsInMinute 60
```

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
#define secondsInHour 3600;          
#define secondsInMinute 60;
```

has following issues:

- you should not use `#define` in this situation at all
- if you use `#define` better use MACRO name in  uppercase to avoid collision
- if you use `#define` do not put semicolon at the end

so either:

```
const int secondsInHour = 3600;          
const int secondsInMinute = 60;
```

or

```
#define secondsInHour 3600
#define secondsInMinute 60
```

or even better

```
#define SECONDS_IN_HOUR 3600
#define SECONDS_IN_MINUTE 60
```

but first variant is prefered as it would not give unexpected surprises like this

Comment: Are #defines only for use in C then?

Comment: @Froobyflake defines confuse compilers and programmers in every language better avoid them for your own sanity

Comment: @Froobyflake there are certain situations when macro is not avoidable in C++, but if it can be done by C++ itself it should be done that way, preprocessor is too simple and diagnostic is very hard if something screwed on that level. You already meet this problem - error message is very confusing

Comment: I would even suggest `constexpr` instead of mere `const` in the first variant. There's no need to have instance of those values during runtime as globals.